# CUDA debug invalid kernel image error

Tags: cuda

I wrote the following CUDA kernel and am trying to load it into a module:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"   // ensure function name to be exactly "vadd"
{
    __global__ void vadd(const float *a, const float *b, float *c)
    {
        int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        printf("Thread id %d\n", i);
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

I compile it to ptx code using the following command:

```
nvcc -ptx -arch=sm_20 vadd.cu
```

When trying to load this file into a module using `cuModuleLoad` I get a CUDA 200 error (invalid kernel image). How can I find out what is wrong with the kernel image? I have tried `ptxas`, but according to that, the generated ptx code is fine.

**Edit**: This is the code I am using to load the module:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void check(CUresult err) {
  if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error %i\n", err);
  }
  assert(err == CUDA_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *cuda = dlopen("libcuda.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    assert(cuda != NULL);

    printf("cuInit\n");
    CUresult (*Init)() = (CUresult (*)()) dlsym(cuda, "cuInit");
    check(Init());

    printf("cuDeviceGet\n");
    CUresult (*DeviceGet)(CUdevice *, int) = (CUresult (*)(CUdevice *, int)) dlsym(cuda, "cuDeviceGet");
    CUdevice device;
    check(DeviceGet(&device, 0));

    printf("cuCtxCreate\n");
    CUresult (*CtxCreate)(CUcontext * , unsigned int, CUdevice) = (CUresult (*)(CUcontext * , unsigned int, CUdevice)) dlsym(cuda, "cuCtxCreate");
    CUcontext context;
    check(CtxCreate(&context, 0, device));

    printf("cuModuleLoad\n");
    CUresult (*ModuleLoad)(CUmodule *, const char*) = (CUresult (*)(CUmodule *, const char*)) dlsym(cuda, "cuModuleLoad");
    CUmodule mod;
    check(ModuleLoad(&mod, "vadd.ptx"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just an aside: According to the documentation, `cuModuleLoad` should never cause a `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE`. Have you other cases where the call worked in general (e.g. an empty kernel, without printf statements, compiled against sm_10 or so)?

Comment: @Marco13 Are you sure: [CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE during cuModuleLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844976/cuda-error-invalid-image-during-cumoduleload)?

Comment: Sorry, I was just mentioning that it is not mentioned in the documentation ( http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html#group__CUDA__MODULE ), but maybe it can occur in practice anyhow

Comment: Can you show the host code which is attempting to load and JIT the PTX. In my experience, this sort of failure usually means you are trying to load a file which isn't either valid PTX or a CUBIN image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to [Why cuCtxCreate creates old context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721556/why-cuctxcreate-creates-old-context): you are using `cuCtxCreate` directly, which gives you an old API context (v3.1) incompatible with your usage of `printf`. You can check the API version with `cuCtxGetApiVersion`. If you switch to `cuCtxCreate_v2`, which is normally used through some `#define`'s in `cuda.h`, you'll get a more recent API context.

In order to spot this discrepancy, I've run your sample with `LD_DEBUG=symbols`, and compared it to using the CUDA API directly (since it properly runs your sample PTX). Comparing symbol resolutions, the big difference was the call to `cuCtxCreate`:

```
cuCtxCreate(...)
    symbol=cuCtxCreate_v2;  lookup in file=./test [0]
    symbol=cuCtxCreate_v2;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0]
```

... which in your original code, using `dlsym(..., "cuCtxCreate")` mapped directly to `cuCtxCreate`.